# Flash programming on Iphone

Tags: iphone, flash, actionscript-3

is there any decent tutorial for flash programming on iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have CS5 you can start an iphone project using the IDE or compile from the command line. Here's a tutorial on the latter:

http://www.theflashguy.co.uk/blog/?p=3